# Can a DynamoDB Condition Expression work on just the Partition Key of a table with a Composite Key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table, with a composite key, which looks like this:

| PK | SK | Type | Email | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER#A | USER#A | User | a@example.com |  |
| USER#A | BUG#1 | Bug |  | This looks ok |
| USER#B | BUG#2 | Bug |  | My user wasn't created first! |

I'd like to ensure that a "User" record exists before adding a related "Bug" record - So the 3rd item here is incorrect.

When I *put* a bug item with the condition `attribute_exists(PK)`, the condition is never true. When I remove the condition, I end up with a that third row; A Bug with no corresponding User.

My understanding is that `attribute_exists()` only looks at items with the combined composite key, and not across the whole table, regardless of which attribute you supply.

Is there a method of ensuring an item with the same Partition Key exists, while ignoring the Sort Key in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DynamoDB condition expressions can be confusing, and the docs can compound that problem!

The DynamoDB condition expression works by 1) finding the item, 2) evaluating the condition expression, and finally 3) writing to the database if the condition evaluates to true.

I assume your `put` operation looks something like this:

```
ddbClient.put({
  TableName: "YOUR TABLE",
  Item: {
    PK: "USER#B",
    SK: "BUG#2",
    Type "Bug",
    Description: "My user wasn't created first!"
  },
  ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(PK)"
})
```

In this example, DynamoDB first tries to find the item with PK: "USER#B" SK: "BUG#2", which does not exist.  As you're experiencing, this item will *not* be written to DynamoDB because an item with that primary key does not exist.

The problem you are seeing, as you've alluded to in your question, is that a `CondttionExpression` applies to only a *single* item.  However, you are trying to conditionally `put` an item in the database by applying the condition to *another* item.  That is a great candidate for a DynamoDB [transaction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html).

Transactions let you group operations together in an all-or-nothing operation.  If one of the operations in your transaction fails, the entire transaction will fail and none of the operations will apply.

You can achieve what you are after by taking this approach

```
ddbClient.transactWriteItems({
    TransactItems=[
    { "PUT":
        {
          TableName: "YOUR TABLE",
          Item: {
            PK: "USER#B",
            SK: "BUG#2",
            Type "Bug"
          }
        }
    },
    { "ConditionCheck":
        {
          TableName: "YOUR TABLE",
          Item: {
            PK: "USER#B",
            SK: "USER#B"
          },
          ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(PK)"
        }
    }
  ]

})
```

In the above transaction, I'm using a [ConditionCheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ConditionCheck.html) to confirm the existence of a user before entering the bug. If the user does not exist, the transaction will fail and the bug won't be written to DDB.

For a more thorough explanation of DynamoDB Condition Expressions, I highly recommend you check out [Understanding DynamoDB Condition Expressions](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-condition-expressions/) by Alex Debrie.

Comment: Thanks Seth. I just found Alex's article while I was waiting for your answer. I also tried transactions, but the local database implementation doesn't support them (and I'd like to be able to test/debug offline)

Comment: That's too bad re: your local setup not supporting transactions.  I'm not sure what you're using, but I know DynamoDB local added transaction support in late 2019.  Perhaps worth a look if you want to confine your tests to a local environment.